# How to print panel with windows form

Tags: c#, .net, printing, panel, draw

I need to print a panel(with many subpanel like tablepanellayout) in windows form.

I have seen many solutions such as draw as bitmap with capture screen - that give me correct form but my text and image is very blurred or draw by access all controls in that panels and draw by string or bitmap , it okays but I think it must have better solution.

Thx for read my problem and very thx for giving me a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont like the approach of bitmap image. what can be done is use of reportviewer and design the content you want to print. and Pass on the Data to the report viewer. there you can have the flexibity to print as well as export to other formats.
A Sample can be found in the following link to get started.
[Click on this Link](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/?Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinFor)